# Freeform 4.0.12 ceate form button missing in firefox ie and chrome

Tags: ee2, solspace-freeform

Hi guys I just installed freeform and cant create a new form when I am inside the form window and click "new form". The form creation page where I enter the form details opens but there is no create or submit button visible to save my work. Is this only available with pro?

Surely someone else has seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you may need to reinstall the add-on's themes. You should see a "Save" button at the very bottom of the form creation form.

I can't vouch for EE (where I do sometimes encounter issues like this) but it works fine in Chrome.

Which versions of EE and IE are you using?