# Freeform: No submit button on new form or duplicate form screen?

Tags: solspace-freeform

Am I nuts? Did I install the module wrong? I don't see a submit button to confirm my changes within the module. Any ideas? I can't add a field either. Button is there in that case but submitting does not do anything. Thx.

update: I'm too new to answer my own question so I'll edit:

Found the answer after I jumped the gun:

[Freeform 4.0.12 ceate form button missing in firefox ie and chrome](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12936/freeform-4-0-12-ceate-form-button-missing-in-firefox-ie-and-chrome?rq=1)

I was missing the themes. Sheeeeeit, as Clay Davis would say, who knew you had to install those files too, to make the thing work?

You put the freeform folder under "third party" in the module distribution under [eebase] >  themes > third party on your server.

Anyway I'm happy now, for now.

/amy

Comment: Hi Amy, glad you figured it out. For posterity's sake, please post your solution as an answer and accept it. Answering your own questions is encouraged and will help others to find the answer and to know this question is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Reposting Amy's answer from above:

Found the answer after I jumped the gun:

Freeform 4.0.12 ceate form button missing in firefox ie and chrome

I was missing the themes. Sheeeeeit, as Clay Davis would say, who knew you had to install those files too, to make the thing work?

You put the freeform folder under "third party" in the module distribution under [eebase] > themes > third party on your server.

Comment: Hi, please accept this as an answer. So unanswered questions section can be cleared up. Thanks